# Fill an array in the spaces thay arnt already defined (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

i would to call this function when added new food to my game. The amount of food is bought in by the parenthesis. I had a go and my code is below

```
function SpawnFood10(Amount) //Add a Food to the board
{
for (var i = 0; i < Amount; i++) {
var j = i;
while (FoodList[j] === undefined){
    FoodList[j] = new Food(); //Add a new Food and initialise it
    FoodList[j].init();
    FoodList[j].FoodValue = 10;
    }
    j++
}
}
```

So it will loop the code the amount of times as the amount of food i pass.
J will then become the lowest space in an array and will go up with i.
While the item number j is undefined in the array, add a new food. if not, keep running the loop until j isnt defined, then repeat the for loop.

I think im stuck in an infite loop because the webpage just doesnt load

Comment: How Food is implemented?

Comment: it runs another function that draws in on the canvas. The add food bit definitly works, its until i tried adding it just in empty spaces, thats where i had the problem

Comment: Try adding some alert in multiple points of the code to understand when something goes wrong

Comment: FoodList seems undefined

Comment: Its declare it as {} as the start of the program but as the game is running, it has elements filled

Comment: If it is declared as {} the while loop will loop forever because FoodList[n] is undefined for any n

Comment: I believe that there's a better way of achieving what you're looking for.

Comment: oh yeh! could i put (if foodlist.length != 0) do the for loop